# Embedding Event / Calendar Data in RSS

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss, calendar, feed

What is the standard way for embedding Event/Calendar data into RSS? Is there an extension to RSS to support this?

I would like a simple way to navigate a blog's RSS feed and pull events from items for republishing to another system. I don't want to go off and do something custom I'd like to take advantage of the accepted standard here.

Bonus: do you know of what plugin to use on the Wordpress side to add event/calendar support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *was* a standard: http://www.ilrt.bris.ac.uk/discovery/2002/01/cal-rss/index.html

However, I would advocate just working off the Google Calendar Data API: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html#Parameters

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a category just for events/custom post type and publish them as posts.  That hooks you into the RSS system automatically.  Custom fields would be used to handle event metadata (time, location, etc).

There are bunch of event plugins but few of them do the posts w/custom fields thing.  These two are likely candidates:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/calendar-press/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kino-event-calendar-plugin/

If you want to take a DIY approach, this is the tutorial I worked from:

http://wptheming.com/2010/08/how-to-make-an-events-custom-post-type/